# source not found for source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate

Tags: bash, pipenv

I'm trying to learn how to use pipenv, and while I can start it and use it from the shell, I can't work out how to open in from a script, the tutorial I am using says to write the following file:

```
#!/bin/sh

export FLASK_APP=./myapp/index.py

source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate

flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

as a shell script, but I get the following error:

```
./bootstrap.sh: 5: source: not found
* Serving Flask app "./catalogueService/index.py"
* Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "index".
```

The could not import index, is fine, I can work with that, what I don't know is what:

```
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
```

Does, and what it should really be so it can find pipenv, I installed it using pip the usual way. Why is it not finding it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Linux or macOS:**

```
source "$(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate"
```

**On Windows:**

```
source "$(pipenv --venv)/Scripts/activate"
```

## OR

```
activate(){
    activate_file=$(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
    if [ -e "$activate_file" ]; then
        . $activate_file

        # the pipenv shell normally enables these as well
        export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
        export PIPENV_ACTIVE=1

        if [ -f "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/.project" ]; then
            cd $(cat "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/.project")
        fi
        return
    fi
}
```

Comment: Ah just seen I'm missing quotes

Comment: You can create a bash class and use that to activate the env. Please check the updated code

Comment: I'm still getting source not found, I'm on linux mint

Comment: I'm a complete dunderhead, I had it right all along, the shell file sits in the folder and I had the folder name in the path. This is now solved and I thank you for responding so quickly by the way

Comment: Sometimes this happens. Indeed it was a good learning. :)